# How to test actors with components injected by Guice in Play! scala 2.5

Tags: scala, akka, guice, actor, playframework-2.5

I'm using Guice to inject components inside an actor as it is explained in the [Play! Scala 2.5 documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAkka#dependency-injecting-child-actors).
In my application, I inject `unshortLinksFactory: UnshortLinks.Factory` in my classes and I create a new actor like this:

`val unshortLinksActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(unshortLinksFactory(ws)))`

The problem is that I cannot inject components in my test class (can I?) otherwise the test are not started. (Please note that I use Scalatest.)

How can I create the actor in my tests? It's fine if I can create it like:

`val unshortLinksActor = system.actorOf(Props(unshortLinksFactory(ws)))`

but the best would be to be able to create it with `TestActorRef` from `Akka.testKit` in order to have access to the `underlyingActor`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I have been struggling with the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do in order to test it is:

I extends the test class with `TestKit(ActorSystem("testSystem"))`.

Then I create the `Props` like this:

```
  lazy val unshortLinkFactoryProps = Props(unshortLinkFactory(
    dbConfigProvider = dbConfProvider)
```

Here `dbConfProvider` is created like this but could also be mocked:

```
  lazy val appBuilder = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
  lazy val injector = appBuilder.injector()
  lazy val dbConfProvider = injector.instanceOf[DatabaseConfigProvider]
```

Finally I can have an actorRef like this:

```
val actorRef = TestActorRef[UnshortLinksActor](unshortLinksFactoryProps)
```

And I can access the methods inside my actor with `actorRef.underlyingActor`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  there is another actor that injects the unshortLinksFactory `class LinksProcessor @Inject()(us: UnshortLinks.Factory) extends Actor`.  the goal is when that actor uses the factory internally it uses a TestProbe from the akkaTest kit.

Comment: I understood well the question since it's me who asked it :). Not sure to understand your comment on the other hand. Let me know what you don't understand

Comment: The issue I have struggled with and thought the first question was asking was how to get access or inject a mock actor that is injected as a factory.  In this example you are creating an actor with dependencies that come pre instantiated.  This is what I want to do: `class GlobalLinks @Inject()(us: UnshortLinks.Factory) extends Actor { context.actorOf(Props(us()) ! "stuff"}`  Then in the test be able to do something like `injector.bind[UnshortLinks.Factory].toInstance(TestProbe().ref)` then do  `testProbe.expectMsg("stuff")`